# Python reading a file from blob storage on azure using argparse is returning an error of attribute not found

Tags: python, file, argparse

We are trying to add a TOML file as an argument when we want to run the following:

`python src/main --file=something.toml`

Within the argument parser function, we've added this line:

```
def parse_args(activity_choices, country_choices):
    parse = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ...
    parse.add_argument('--file', type = argparse.FileType('r'))
    parser = parse.parse_args()
    file = parser.file.readlines()
```

with printing the file that is of type `list`, using:

`print(file[0])`

We see that the only returned value is `[mainparams]` and not the whole list of values inside of mainparams.

We tried the solution of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64427533/reading-a-toml-config-file-from-cli-with-argparse):

```
toml = tomli.loads(parser.file)
```

But we used tomli, as it was already used in different place within the script.

the error was:

> AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'replace'

We need to get the country and activity values into variable in order to proceed.

Here is a toml example:

```
[mainparams]
country='USA'
activity='HEALTH'

[optionalparams]
csv_path=TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues here:

1. You are calling `tomli.loads` on an `_io.TextIOWrapper`.
   You need to `read()` the file first or use a binary file reader.
2. Your `optionalparams.csv_path`, as a boolean, does not [conform to the TOML spec](https://toml.io/en/v1.0.0#boolean). It should be lowercase.

This works:

```py
import argparse
import tomli

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--file", type=argparse.FileType("r"))
args = parser.parse_args()

file = tomli.loads(args.file.read())
```

with this TOML file:

```ini
[mainparams]
country='USA'
activity='HEALTH'

[optionalparams]
csv_path=true
```

Notice that `optionalparams.csv_path` is all lowercase.

---

If you don't want to call `args.file.read()` you can load the file as a binary and pass the object to `tomli.load`:

```py
import argparse
import tomli

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--file", type=argparse.FileType("rb")) # Notice "rb" here
args = parser.parse_args()

file = tomli.load(args.file) # Notice `toml.load` here
```